# Xamarin.Forms ListView ItemTapped with Corcav.Behaviors not working?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use the `Xamarin.Forms` behaviors at `corradocavalli/Corcav.Behaviors`, however I'm not able to get the binding of the `ListView` `ItemTapped` event working correctly to the `ViewModel`.

In my **ListView** I am using:-

```
<behaviors:EventToCommand  
    BindingContext="{behaviors:RelativeContext Name=MyPageName}" 
    EventName="ItemTapped"                                  
    CommandName="OnItemSelected"                               
    PassEventArgument="True" 
/>
```

and in my **ViewModel** I am using:-

```
public Command<ItemTappedEventArgs> OnItemSelected { get; private set; }
```

Constructor:-

```
this.OnItemSelected = 
      new Command<ItemTappedEventArgs>(async (e) => await MyHandlerForOnItemSelected(e));
```

and then finally:-

```
private async Task MyHandlerForOnItemSelected(ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
   ....
}
```

But the `xaml` markup is causing the app not to start, and hangs, as I am obviously doing something wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get any errors? What do they say?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis It just hangs the app and doesn't load the xaml page.  When I remove the behaviors markup in the xaml, the app shows the page.

Comment: Please check the application output window, maybe something is in there

Comment: @GeraldVersluis There is nothing in the Output window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
          <behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:BehaviorCollection>
              <behaviors:EventToCommand
                  BindingContext="{behaviors:RelativeContext MPage}"
                  EventName="ItemTapped"
                  CommandName="OnItemSelected"
                  PassEventArgument="True"/>
            </behaviors:BehaviorCollection>
          </behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </ListView>
```

This code works fine along with the code shared by you, am able to handle itemtapped event.

Comment: For whatever reason, the code started working later on.  Ahhh the beauty of Xamarin development :-D